# How to Back when CollectionView Image was Zoom

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Here I Zoom Collectionview Cell Image when it was Selected But now i want to make that when touch up inside image View then Back to the Collection View How it is Possible please give me Solution

Here My Code is

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally];
[self zoomToSelectedImage:indexPath];
}
-(void)zoomToSelectedImage:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSDictionary *dict = [self.imagesa objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
NSString *img=[dict valueForKey:@"link"];

UIImageView *zoomImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[zoomImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:img]];
zoomImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
zoomImage.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
zoomImage.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchgesture=[[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchGestureDetected:)];
[pinchgesture setDelegate:self];
[zoomImage addGestureRecognizer:pinchgesture];

UIPanGestureRecognizer *pangausture=[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGestureDetected:)];
[pangausture setDelegate:self];
[zoomImage addGestureRecognizer:pangausture];
self.imagecollection.hidden=TRUE;


CGRect zoomFrameTo = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
UICollectionViewCell *cellToZoom =(UICollectionViewCell *)[self.imagecollection cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
CGRect zoomFrameFrom = cellToZoom.frame;
[self.view addSubview:zoomImage];
zoomImage.frame = zoomFrameFrom;
zoomImage.alpha = 0.2;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.01 animations:
 ^{
     zoomImage.frame = zoomFrameTo;
     zoomImage.alpha = 1;
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Here Imagecollection is my Collectionview.

Answer (score 0):

You are not zooming collectionView with using standard methods:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath    
// [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
```

In your case you created `UIImageView` in full screen with the same content as in the cell and added this `UIImageView` as a `subview` to cover everything. So, if you animate `zoomImage.alpha` to `0` and unhide the collectionview you get what you want. Don´t forget to `removeFromSuperview` zoomImage on completion.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a tap gesture recogniser, or even a transparent button covering the same area as the zoomed image. As #kabarga says don't forget to removeFromSuperview to get rid of your imageView.